# How to use gcp signed url with custom headers in Go

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, pre-signed-url

I am trying to set the x-goog-meta-reference in the header section dynamically so i want to pass an argument called reference in the function signature and assign that to the x-goog-meta-reference in the header. See `x-goog-meta-reference` in my code sample below. I followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/canonical-requests#required-query-parameters) link regarding canonical requests.

My sample code is from [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers#storage-signed-url-object-go) but it is the edited version of my prod code.

```
func GenerateSignedURL(ctx context.Context, bucket string, key string, expiration time.Time,
) (string, error) {
    gcsClient, err := storage.NewClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("storage.NewClient: %v", err)
    }
    defer gcsClient.Close()

    storage.SignedURL()
    opts := &storage.SignedURLOptions{
        Scheme:      storage.SigningSchemeV4,
        Method:      "PUT",
        ContentType: "text/csv",
        Headers:     []string{
            "x-goog-meta-reference: xxx", // << I want xxx value to be whatever I pass to this function as an arg
        },
        Expires:     expiration,
    }

    url, err := gcsClient.Bucket(bucket).SignedURL(key, opts)
    if err != nil {
        log.WithContext(ctx).Warn("Failed to generate a GCS signed URL")
        return "", err
    }

    return url, nil
}
```

I tried looking at some examples but all of them are s3 and I did not run into any gcp sample code. However, I did find [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/1511) issue but i was not able to figure it out myself.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what issue you're encountering. What (specifically) doesn't work correctly with your approach?

Comment: Sorry if my question is not clear but I am trying to set the `x-goog-meta-reference` in the header section dynamically so i want to pass an argument called `reference` in the function signature and assign that to the `x-goog-meta-reference` in the header. I hope this is clear now @DazWilkin

Comment: I understand that from your code. But, evidently (because you posted a question), it's not working. Why not? What happens?

Comment: I don't know how to set the `x-goog-reference` like if you look at all the examples, the values are hardcoded for headers - for instance `Headers: []string{....}`. All those headers are hard-coded with a value and in my case, it is different. It is a custom header and i want the value to be what I pass to the function. What i need help with is, how to set the value of `x-goog-meta-reference` in the code in the `Header`. I don't know the syntax for that as all the sample code that i have seen have the values all predefined. @DazWilkin

Comment: The code works as expected if I don't have `x-goog-meta-reference` header. I just want to incorporate that into the code when the url is generated.

Comment: You'll obviously need to provide the variable to the function and can then simply: `fmt.Sprintf("x-goog-meta-reference:%s",xxx)`, for example.

Comment: I just tested that out before i saw your comment. Yea, that works. I was thinking, maybe, there is a better way way to do it since it is prod code but i guess `fmt.Sprintf` would suffice in this situation? @DazWilkin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dazwilkin [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71105918/how-to-use-gcp-signed-url-with-custom-headers-in-go#comment125696187_71105918), `fmt.Sprintf` is good enough for this case, but you can also use this [library](https://github.com/DKbyo/go-stringhttpheader) that I ported from [mozilla](https://github.com/mozillazg/go-httpheader)

```golang
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "cloud.google.com/go/storage"
    "github.com/dkbyo/go-stringhttpheader"
)

type Headers struct {
    GoogleMetaReference string `header:"x-goog-meta-reference"`
}

func GenerateSignedURL(bucket string, key string, expiration time.Time,
) (string, error) {
    ctx := context.Background()
    gcsClient, err := storage.NewClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("storage.NewClient: %v", err)
    }
    defer gcsClient.Close()
    headers := Headers{
        GoogleMetaReference: "xxx",
    }
    fmt.Print(stringhttpheader.Encode(headers))
    stringheaders, _ := stringhttpheader.Encode(headers)
    //storage.SignedURL()
    opts := &storage.SignedURLOptions{
        Scheme:      storage.SigningSchemeV4,
        Method:      "PUT",
        ContentType: "text/csv",
        Headers:     stringheaders,
        Expires:     expiration,
    }

    url, err := gcsClient.Bucket(bucket).SignedURL(key, opts)
    if err != nil {
        log.WithContext(ctx).Warn("Failed to generate a GCS signed URL")
        return "", err
    }

    return url, nil
}
```

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks for sharing it.